# Rails routes based on current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, routes, rails-routing

I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast) rails cast to create authentication for a rails project. My routes currently look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  get "new_photo" => "users#edit", :as => "new_photo"
  root :to => "users#new"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
end
```

How to I edit this file so that the root will be pointing to "messages#new", if a user is logged in and "users#new" when no user is logged in? I tried many of the solutions on other pages, but they didnt work (they were probably for devise). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to handle this in your controller.

**routes.rb**

```
root :to => "users#new"
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
  return redirect_to new_messages_url if current_user
  # normal controller code below...
end
```

This will redirect the logged_in user (`current_user`) to the new messages page if already logged in. I'm just assuming that `current_user` holds your user data, it may be different for your application.

Comment: You will have to `return redirect_to ...` to avoid rendering after the redirect.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but would suggest to optimize it for the most frequent scenario. If you know that, for example, 80% of the visits will be from logged in users, then you should go to `messages#new` first, and redirect only the exceptions.

Comment: @tompave I agree. I set it up with the assumption that logged-out users would visit the root more frequently. Thanks for bringing that up

Answer (score 0):

write it in any home controler.

```
def set_roots   
  if current_user      
    redirect_to dashboard_home_index_path
  else      
    redirect_to home_index_path  
  end    
end
```

in routes.rb file

```
root :to => 'home#set_roots'

match "/find_roots" => "home#set_roots"
```