# Rails, Active Admin, Devise, routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, cancancan

I've been working with Rails, Active Addmin and cancancan. Everything is working fine except one thing. Recently I have added separate namespaces for my **admin** type users and **clients**.

Before that change, I redirected all authenticated users to the same active admin dashboard in such way (routes.rb):

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do  
        root :to => 'admin/dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'pages#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

Currently I need to somehow add additional condition that will be checking if authenticated user has role **admin** or **client**.

My idea was to make sth like that:

```
devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do 
      if current_user.role?(:Architect) || current_user.role?(:Admin) 
        root :to => 'admin/dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
      else 
        root :to => 'clients/dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_client
      end
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'pages#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

But I am getting error: **undefined local variable or method `current_user'**
Does anybody know how I can check user's role in routes? Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You can check for user role in applicationcontroller before action filter. I have not accessed current_user in routes.rb before.

Comment: What about this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681957/rails-routes-based-on-current-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root is a config file responsible for routes definition, you can't access any session variables in config files.

If you want to redirect user after sign in you can use `after_sign_in_path_for` method in `Devise::SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if resource.role?(:Architect) || resource.role?(:Admin) 
            authenticated_root_url
        else
            authenticated_client_url
        end 
    end
end
```

In your route you need to indicate the custom sessions_controller

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Muhammad's suggestions are also valuable, but this solution required almost no changes in the code.

1. From routes.rb I removed the entire block starting at devise_scope ...
2. I added: 

 `devise_for :users, 
    controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions', 
                  registrations: 'users/registrations', 
                  passwords: 'users/passwords'}, 
                  path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }`

Comment: 3. in the /users/sessions_controller.rb I added:

`def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if resource.role?(:Architect) || resource.role?(:Admin) 
            admin_dashboard_path
        else
            clients_dashboard_path
        end 
    end`

Comment: @Michal you will also need to add before filter in case if user manually enters the url.

Answer (score 1):

**Page Controller :**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :check_route, :only => [:index]

  def check_route
    return unless user_signed_in?
    if current_user.role?(:Architect) || current_user.role?(:Admin)
      redirect_to :controller => 'admin/dashboard', :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to :controller => 'clients/dashboard', :action => 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'pages#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
```